# Android - Calling finish() calls onPause(), but then calls SimpleAdapter's getView() method before onStop/Destroy, causing crash

Tags: java, android, simpleadapter, activity-finish

I have a SimpleAdapter in my home screen, where it's getView() method is being called at a weird time. In my onOptionsItemSelected function, I have a logout option.

```
            case R.id.menu_admin_home_logout:
                finish();
                Intent f = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
                f.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(f);
                return true;
```

When I select this logout menu item, I would expect:

1. onPause()
2. onStop()
3. onDestroy()

Instead, I receive the following:

1. onPause() called
2. Home Screen Activity is closed ( visually only - confirmed this with a breakpoint after finish() )
3. Login screen is shown
4. The Home Screen activity's SimpleAdapter getView() method is called.
5. Fatal Exception

All of the Home Screen's variables are null when getView() is called. The onStop() and onDestroy() class methods are never called due to the crash. Just in case of a duplicate activity running, I checked for the onResume() method being called after onPause() - it is not being called. So, I think this rules out duplicate activity possibility.

**Note:** This seems to be an issue with Android API 30, (OS 11). I don't have the issue on my personal device, which is running OS 12. My client has this crash, and my new emulator (also API 30), crashes here as well. I also didn't have this issue in the past with OS's 9 and 10, so just 11 as far as I can see.

Thoughts on this? I posted the full crash below.

For now, I am just surrounding the method's content with a try/catch and returning the view. I consider this to be a band-aid solution, and highly prefer to find and solve the root issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.xxx.xxx.activity_screens.HomeScreen$1.getView(HomeScreen.java:250)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2067)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1492)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1802)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2184)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Hi
Did you write any piece of code related to SimpleAdapter in onPause or onStop or onDestroy?

Comment: @FoxDonut just remove this code `finish();`

Comment: As a @MDev said  you are you calling `finish();` method before starting a another activity you should always first start activity and then `finish();`

Comment: @MobileTeamADR-Flutter No, I do not have any SimpleAdapter code in onPause or onDestroy. This is why I thought this was so odd.

Comment: @MDev I have tried removing finish() and it doesn't change the outcome. The exception is still being caught here.

Comment: @VishalBeep I have tried moving finish()  after startActivity(), but the result is the same.

Comment: I would just like to point this out again - this isn't happening on Android 12 or other operating systems. What is the possibility that Android 11 has an odd bug? I am also getting a firebase issue with Android 11 only. Seems a little suspicious to me.